# unable to create a executable spring boot jar by the bootJar task

Tags: spring-boot, corda

basically I need to create a spring boot jar to run system spring-server service on my server
    import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

```
ext {
    spring_boot_version = '1.5.7.RELEASE'
    spring_version = '4.3.11.RELEASE'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases' }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils'

bootJar {
    basName = 'corda-webserver'
    version = '1.0.0'
}
```

How can I achieve this is there something wrong with gradle dependencies or plugins?

I tried springboot task as well

Comment: rest dependencies are of spring boot starter and web socket etc. Couldn't post it due to the length error.

Comment: I get the error : Could not find method bootJar() for arguments [build_aiajfuo6ddndhi3i8gtl3zxds$_run_closure9@65d39daa] on project ':clients' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: You don't appear to have applied Spring Boot's plugin to the project. Also, `bootJar` is new in Spring Boot 2.0 and you appear to be using 1.5.7.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I upgraded the version to 2.0.0 . here is my boot jar bootJar {
    baseName "jarName"
    launchScript()
    version = '2.0.0'
}

Comment: but I get the error now :  Unresolved reference: springframework, Unresolved reference: SpringBootApplication, Unresolved reference: java, and many more such errors unresolved reference

Comment: Hey I resolved the above error but now getting this with spring boot version 2.0.0 error: cannot find symbol
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter;
                                                 ^

Comment: What dependencies have you declared in your `build.gradle`? Can you edit your question to include all of it?

Answer (score 0):

So there's not enough information here to be sure of what the issue could be; so here are a few ideas.

Start by cleaning gradle cache. ./gradlew clean

Obviously the issue here is dependencies, you need to make sure gradle is able to build your project, and download dependencies.

./gradlew deployNodes (if you're using one of the corda sample projects) will build all of the files locally and should pull in the dependencies for you.

R3 now uses software.r3.com as the 'official' link to the artifact repository, you may want to take a look there and maybe look at whether the downloads are still good.

good luck!